# calendarextender is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

im using ajaxtoolkit in c# asp.net,
calendarextendar not working properly..

my code is,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="calaender.aspx.cs" Inherits="BorvoPharmaceuticals.calaender" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>
```

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                  PopupButtonID="TextBox1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                  Format="dd-MM-yyyy"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
</div>
```

ajaxtoolkit reference removed also re added....
but when i click textbox calendar is not display..

Comment: Have you added `ToolkitScriptManager` ?

Comment: No exceptions? Did you check Chrome and/or IE console for errors?

Comment: Have you added ToolkitScript Manager and AJAX Toolkit refecence

Comment: yes i added script manager in site.master page file

Comment: @SaranyaLoganathan if so you have to change your tag prefix for `CalendarExtender` according to your `ToolkitScriptManager `.For more info follow this [AJAX Calender Extender](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/407460/How-to-use-ASP-NET-AJAX-Calender-Extender)

Comment: not working in IE/Mozila too...

Comment: i use namespace as, ** 
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="asp" %>**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're assigning the tagPrefix of "asp" to the `AJAXControlToolkit` controls.

```
 <%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Remove the reference to AJAX Control Toolkit and re-add it.follow this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="TxtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
                      PopupButtonID="txtExpDate" TargetControlID="txtExpDate" 
                      Format="dd-MM-yyyy">
</cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: i did all the changes but not working still.. what i did wrong in this section...

Comment: @SaranyaLoganathan where you have added `ajaxtoolkit prefix`..Add `ajaxtoolkit prefix` in your aspx file

Comment: Not sure what error occured ;) Make sure you have AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your bin folder. I recommand you this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/407460/How-to-use-ASP-NET-AJAX-Calender-Extender)..

Comment: @SaranyaLoganathan what was the issue ??

Comment: ajaxtoolkitinstaller problem... i remove all ajax extension and re installed.. then its workig properly...

Answer (score 2):

I copy the code and its working fine :
Different from your code is that I added `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` and `ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender`

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="TxtDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                                      Enabled="True" PopupButtonID="txtExpDate" 
                                      TargetControlID="txtExpDate" Format="dd-MM-yyyy">
        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yah but not working... i used 
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="asp" %>

Comment: will you try to add ajaxtoolkit prefix and then rename it on the<add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />