# datetime picker for textbox is not displaying in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Calendar Extender is not working for my simple asp application with c#

I have used a textbox with calendar extension, when i click on textbox calendar is not displaying for selecting a date.
i have used script manager in master page itself.

```
<tr> 
    <td>Time :</td> 
    <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTime" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:TextBox> 
         <asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="TxtTime_ColorPickerExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TxtTime"> </asp:ColorPickerExtender> </td> 
    <td></td> 
</tr>
```

when user clicks on textbox calendar must be displayed and when user select specific date in a calendar, selected date should be displayed in a textbox.

Comment: <tr>
    <td>Time :</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTime" runat="server" Width="250px" AutoPostBack="True"> 
        </asp:TextBox>
  <asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="TxtTime_ColorPickerExtender" runat="server" 
   Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TxtTime">
  </asp:ColorPickerExtender>
 </td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: What have you tried ? It would be better if you will show piece of code which you have tried?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad could you please flag as duplicate instead of constructing custom comments (if you actually think it is duplicate)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calendarextender is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247225/calendarextender-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I know, that this "answer" will not bring your `<asp:ColorPickerExtender />` back, but why don't you use the `TextMode`-attribute of your `<asp:TextBox />` instead?

Give it a try and check out, how the browser does the dirt work for you:

```
<tr> 
    <td>Time:</td> 
    <td> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtTime" runat="server" Width="250px" TextMode="Date" /> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

For more information, check out this write-up: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/776764/%2FTips%2F776764%2FIntroducing-Textmode-in-ASP-NET#Date